# Help identify a frame

Tags: frames

could someone help me identify a mountain bike frame, the rear triangle of the frame has square tubing, it's a late 90s early 00s frame. [image]

Comment: Please have a look at https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1340/10595

Comment: It is fairly distinctive.  Looks like a fairly early aluminum frame.

Comment: I have an older KHS Alight 300 that looks pretty similar.